# Unable to keep preventDefault when using a submitHandler, goes straight to AJAX PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm unable to keep my AJAX call inside the same page. It keeps posting my form without any of the tried preventDefault() tries.

Here's my full code for a form ID "#leadform" and a button ID "#submitButton".

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#submitButton").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#leadform').submit();
});

$("#leadform").validate({

    rules: {
        Mobile: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        Mobile: {
            required: "Please enter a valid phone number"
        },
        email: {
            required: "Please enter your email address"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {

         $("#response").addClass("alert alert-info").text("Do not close this window, it may take a minute to complete!");
        var formData = $('#leadform').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'submit.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'text', // json
            beforeSend: function(data) {
                //console.log(data);
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#response").removeClass("alert-info").delay(200).addClass("alert-success").text("Thank you for your request! You can now close this window");
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log('An error occurred.');
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

});
});
```

I have tried a lot of options, read about all the SO posts and none helped.

Alternatives I tried are:

- Without $('#leadform').submit(); called seperately, but from within the same function.
- e.preventDefault from within the submithandler (added e to the function of course).
- Tried with and without that return false line.

Whatever I tried (tried for hours literally), it goes straight to the php file. When I remove the validate function and include the ajax normally via the submit button click function, it works fine and as expected (it just won't validate my last step in the form wizzard so i need to make a validation for that last step.

I hope anybody can help me out.

Thanks.

Added HTML Section (shortened)

```
<form action="submit.php" name="leadform" id="leadform" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" class="js-wizard-validation2-form">
   <div id="_Mobile" class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="Mobile">Mobile Number</label>
      <input type="text" name="Mobile" id="Mobile" minlength="10" maxlength="16" placeholder="Phone number here" class="form-control required input_text" required="">
   </div>
   <div id="_Email" class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="Email">Email Address</label>
      <input type="email" name="Email" id="Email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" placeholder="Email here" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" class="form-control input_text" required="">
   </div>
   <div class="block-content block-content-sm block-content-full bg-body-light rounded-bottom" style="margin-top:20px;">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-alt-secondary" data-wizard="prev">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left mr-1"></i> Previous
            </button>
         </div>
         <div class="col-6 text-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" data-wizard="next">
            Next<i class="fa fa-angle-right ml-1"></i>
            </button>
            <button type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-lg btn-success d-none" data-wizard="finish">
            <i class="fa fa-check mr-1"></i> Submit </button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML also? And what is your desire, I couldn't follow you. Do you just want to avoid redirecting?

Comment: @SMAKSS Yes. We do that all the time but haven't had any luck ever with this validate method.

Comment: Can I see your related HTML, the form part is enough for me.

Comment: @SMAKSS Added, quickly shortened it though, hopefully it is enough (and correctly cut)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.form/), you can actually trigger the validator without submitting the form.

```
var validator = $( "#leadform" ).validate();//your entire validation script goes here, its left out for brevity

$("#submitButton").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    validator.form();
});
```

Comment: Not working either.
Gives a form is not defined error, consolde.log(this.form) gives the correct form, however you cannot call validate.this.form();

Comment: @KimK. it looks like you are adding in extra code that wasn't in my example. You don't need to add the random `this` in there. `var validator = $( "#leadform" ).validate(` is already stating which form to use.

Comment: Of course. Sorry for the confusion. I had that, I was just trying to add info by telling that when I DO add this in the console, it gives some sort of response. The code itself just sits there without any action or warning/error. I added some logging in the submithandler as well, it does not fire.